# create a project for phonegap in ios showing error in terminal not a directory

Tags: cordova

i am creating a phonegap apps in ios.but when i am trying for creating a new project in    xocde by this command. that's showing a error on termial.

```
   Not a directory

/Users/incarnate/Desktop/phonegap/lib/ios/bin/create/desktop/hello com.hello hello
```

Comment: which cordova version are you using.?

Comment: Uninstall old version of phonegap/cordova from the system and try to re-install again cordova 1.5.